# Add additional named groups for regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

With `re.sub` you can use named groups to refer them in the replacement string:

```
import re
re.sub(r"(?P<mygroup>.*):(.*)",
       r"\g<2> AND \g<mygroup>",
       "foo:bar")

-> "bar AND foo"
```

Is there a possibility to supply additional groups, e.g.,

```
re.sub(r"(?P<mygroup>.*):(.*)",
       r"\g<2> AND \g<mygroup> AND \g<anothergroup>",
       "foo:bar",
       supplemental_groups = {"anothergroup" : "hamspam"} )

-> "bar AND foo AND hamspam"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Of course, why not? Call it `anothergroup` and use it. Did your regex fail when you tried this?

Comment: Only those that you define in the regex pattern. What do you need the backreference for?

Answer (score 0):

You may pass a callable as the replacement argument, and you may pass whatever additional "supplemental" groups you need using a lambda:

```py
import re

def repl(m, extra_groups):
    return fr"{m.group(2)} AND {m.group('mygroup')} AND {extra_groups['anothergroup']}"

supplemental_groups = {"anothergroup" : "hamspam"}
print (re.sub(r"(?P<mygroup>.*):(.*)",
    lambda x, extra_groups=supplemental_groups: repl(x, extra_groups),
    "foo:bar"))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1Agdoa). Output: `bar AND foo AND hamspam`.

Comment: Thx, there are, however, some problems I see here. You assume that the regexp is known beforehand, you hard code the group names in repl(). Is is possible to use a replacement string like "\g<2> AND \g<mygroup> AND \g<anothergroup>" here?

Comment: @Horus You will still have to know what part of this string to replace in the `repl` function.

Comment: That is what the "\g<anothergroup>" reference should be for.

Comment: @Horus Whatever, you can't use a named backreference in a string replacement pattern if there is no group with such name in the pattern.